# Did I do this right and how do I do part b of this problem about matrices?

Tags: matrices

Q: "An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is called invertible if $$AB=I_n=BA$$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $B$. In this case, $B$ is called inverse of $A$.
Suppose an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible.

(a) Show that the inverse of $A$ is unique.
 (b) For any $k\in\Bbb{Z}^+$show  that $A^k$ is also invertible and $(A^k)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^k$.

My solution for (a):
Let $B$ and $C$ be inverses of $A$. $$AB=I_n=BA$$ $$AC=I_n=CA$$ $BI_n=B(AC)=(BA)C=I_nC$
$B=C$

Did I do part a correctly and can you help me get started on part b?

Comment: Part (a) correct. For part (b) you will use part (a) namely the inverse is unique and every invertible matrix commutes with its inverse.

Comment: You can use induction for part b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (b), compute the products 
$$A^k(A^{-1})^k,\quad (A^{-1})^kA^k$$
and see what they become.